# Does being accidental aroused then releasing fluid break wudu

Tags: sex, wudu, masturbation, men, ibadah

I become very easily aroused and I release very tiny drop of fluid. For example yesterday I was reading the quran a thought just came to mind and its not that i spent a minute thinking about it in less than 10 seconds I released very tiny drop of fluid which is equal to a millimetre. Im a male 15 years old

This is a frequent problem for me like 4 times a day and its totally unintentional. I try hard to concentrate and to make sure a thought does not come but it just comes randomly out of know where and in less than 10 seconds i release what am is supposed to do. It happens some times when im reading quran, making wudu, or about to pray. While sitting if i put one leg on top of another or if my baby brother sits in my lap the same thing happens.

I understand stand if a fluid is released wudu breaks but this is unintentional a thought just comes and it just happens if this is a frequent problem is there a rule that my wudu does not break because i dont know what to do its very frustrating. This problem is ruining my Ibadah i can t pray or read quran properly. Im a hanafi.

I might be this sensitive due to previous excessive masturbation alhamdulillah I have completely stopped asked for repentance and know i have this problem.

I can only ask this question online due to its context please help me.

Thank you